# Who is the true leader of the One Shadow Nine Fists?

Tags: historys-strongest-disciple-kenichi

All this time, I thought the manga was leading on that Saiga Furinji was the leader, but then  around chapter 570, it turns out some guy named Senzui was disguised as Saiga Furinji. Furthermore, it seems that they both shared the same disciple Satomi.

Was Senzui the One Shadow this entire time? How can they both even train Satomi if Senzui is always disguised and so is Saiga? What on earth is going on?

Lastly, who actually controls (or controlled) the One Shadow Nine Fists ?